# GUI in Stylo in R is not loading (I have already installed XQuartz too)

Tags: r

I have been using the Style package in R for a few years now. The GUI loaded as soon as I typed
library(stylo).

However, I got back into it after a while yesterday and to my surprise GUI would not load. None of the students in my class (on either Mac or Windows) couldn't load it either.

I do not get any error messages either.

Does anyone have a solution?